# JOIN entre tabelas com alguma(s) delas vazias

Tags: query, join

Boa Noite
    Tenho 6 Tabelas  (A,B,C,D,E,F)

```
A tabela  A sempre contém registros  e tem uma chave primaria ID
```

As demais tabelas B,C,D,E e F  todas são filhas da tabela A e tem uma coluna FK_ID  que faz referencia a chave primaria da tabela  A, mas qualquer uma destas tabelas pode não conter nenhum registro, gostaria de saber como posso fazer o joing entre todas tabelas  que mesmo com uma delas não contendo nenhum registro retorne todos os dados da demais. Há alguma maneira de retornar sem usar FULL JOIN ?

Answer (score 1):

Nas tabelas que devem ser exibidas mesmo se não tiver linha correspondente a clausula `ON`, você substitui o `JOIN` ou `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN`.

`INNER JOIN` ou `JOIN` quer dizer que a linha só será mostrada se ela existir nas duas ou mais tabelas que estão sendo comparadas.

`LEFT JOIN` retorna as linhas da tabela caso exista, se não existir ele traz do mesmo jeito. Porém com todas as colunas referentes a essa tabela com o valor `NULL`.